# Multiple languages using HTML5 data attribute

Tags: php, html, internationalization, multiple-languages

I have seen many ways to add multiple languages, I found one I like more than the others. Using HTML5 `data-{string}` they have added `data-translate="USER_PROFILE"`

Then they use a .json file like this:

```
{
    "PAGES": "Pages",
    "LOGIN": "Login",
    "LOG_OUT": "Logout",
    "SIGN_IN": "Sign In",
    "SIGN_UP": "Sign Up",
    "USER_PROFILE": "User Profile"
}
```

How to make that in **PHP** *(database instead of .json)* and **HTML5** when using the `data-something`

I just think it will be easier to add new languages if it runs on the database, or are I'm wrong? What will be the best way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of multi language translation is called `i18n`. You will have to use some library for the same as implementing the whole part is a huge and daunting task. [Here is something to get you started](https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n)

You will still have to create language files for the ones you need to support.

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor there are many other libraries also. I just gave the one on top of google search :D